# Scrapy retry middleware fails with non-standart http status code

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

I am using Scrapy default RetryMiddleware to try redownload failed URLs. I want to process such way pages, which got 429 status code at response ("Too Many Requests").

But I got error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/parse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/parse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 46, in process_response
    response = method(request=request, response=response, spider=spider)
  File "/home/vagrant/parse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py", line 58, in process_response
    reason = response_status_message(response.status)
  File "/home/vagrant/parse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/response.py", line 58, in response_status_message
    reason = http.RESPONSES.get(int(status)).decode('utf8', errors='replace')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I tried to debug problem and found that Scrapy  RetryMiddleware before actually retry to download page try to define reason of previous failing.
So `response_status_message` method try to create string using status code and status text, for example

```
>>> response_status_message(404)
    '404 Not Found'
```

To get response string it uses twisted Response method `http.RESPONSES.get(int(status))`. But in case of custom http status code without using default parameter for `get()` it return NoneType instead of string.

So, Scrapy tries to call `decode('utf8', errors='replace')` for NoneType.

Are there possibility to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually bug in Scrapy library. But it is already fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/65c7c05060fd2d1fc161d4904243d5e0b31e202b#diff-6aafb18d7ff6716d330cf9c8cde7726c) and is placed in RC1.1 [changelogs](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1927)